# SimpleCart JS change color of cart according to quantity

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, simplecart

I'm having trouble trying to use the simpleCart JS events to produce an effect that changes color of the shopping cart according of quantity.

Essentially I am trying to achieve a function like this:
http://shop.hotelcostes.com/en/music/26-hotel-costes-1.html

By using simpleCart js:
http://simplecartjs.org/documentation

I have two scripts so far that work but are not ideal

```
simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function( item ){
    if(simpleCart.quantity() > 0){
        simpleCart.$("#cart").attr( "style" , "color:red" );
}
});


simpleCart.bind( "ready" , function( item ){
    if(simpleCart.quantity() > 0){
        simpleCart.$("#cart").attr( "style" , "color:red" );
}
});
```

The problems:

1. The script with the 'afterAdd' function changes color of the cart normally but when I add the .hide() and .fadeIn() effects the add function continues to work however the hide, fadeIn, or add color effects don't work.
2. SimpleCart only provides an event called 'beforeRemove' but what I really need is some sort of function 'afterRemove' event that recognizes when the quantity reaches 0 and changes the color of the cart accordingly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to afterAdd and use simpleCart.quantity() to get the quantity . Here is a snippet

```
//assuming you div that displays cartinfo has a class "cartInfo"
simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function( item ){
   if(simpleCart.quantity() == 2){
     simpleCart.$(".cart").attr( "style" , "color:red" );
   }else{
     simpleCart.$(".cart").attr( "style" , "color:balck" );
   }
});
simpleCart.bind( "beforeRemove" , function( item ){ 
   if(simpleCart.quantity() > 0 && simpleCart.quantity()-1 == 0){ 
        simpleCart.$("#cart").attr( "style" , "color:black" );   
   }
   return true;
});
```

Comment: I got the first part to work with                      simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function(item){
    simpleCart.$("#cart").attr("style" , "color:red");
});                                                                   I'm not sure if the if/else statement can be tied to the 'afterAdd' function because the after any item is added the quantity will be greater than 0. Is there a way to make a general statement saying that if at anytime the cart quantity equals 0 make it black and if the cart quantity is greater than 0 make it red? Or do these have to be connected with specific functions?

Comment: I tried to add a couple effects but it didn't work. .hide().attr("style","color:red").fadeIn();

Comment: So you want to check the cart content on load of page ? the you can use this : http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/ready-event 
and u can perform any jquery options on the cart info element .. are you getting anyerror ??

Comment: I did need an on load function too for if someone refreshes the page it recognizes if there are items in the cart and makes the cart red. What I need is a function that recognizes the quantity in the cart when an item is removed - I clarified my original question above and added the scripts I have so far.

Comment: you can use the beforeRemove and when u return true the item will be removed. so if you are sure the item can be remove . u can use simpleCart.quantity()-1; and execute your logic .

Comment: Where do you put the return true in the code? Could you write it out please?

Comment: simpleCart.bind( "beforeRemove" , function( item ){
        if(simpleCart.quantity() = 0){
           simpleCart.$("#cart").attr( "style" , "color:black" ); 
        }
    });

Comment: This seems to be on the right track but something is still not working. It removes the item but does not change the color.

Comment: What is your cart element ?? #cart or #cartInfo ?

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I used your answer with a few modifications so you deserve the credit but I would like to post the script with the modifications. Sorry I'm not familiar with protocol should I do that in my original post or edit your answer?

Comment: The script is working for me but let me know if some of the changes aren't semantically correct or foreseeable problems. Thanks again.

Comment: There is one little problem. When the cart is filled with 2 or more of the SAME item and then emptied - the color doesn't change. However if 2 or more of the same item plus another item are in the cart then emptied - the color changes. And if there is only 1 item in the cart then emptied - the color changes. Any item on why this is?